# Dynamic jQuery CSS Property?

Tags: jquery

I am having problems doing the following:

```
var direction = "left";
$('#elem').css({"margin-"+direction: "50px"});
```

Is it not possible to have dynamic properties like this?

Thank you

Comment: Yes... it is possible... Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/cgtnd9wL/

Answer (score 0):

[.css(propertyname, value)](https://api.jquery.com/css/#css-propertyName-value) has a another variation that can take the property name and value as 2 different arguments

```
var direction = "left";
$('#elem').css("margin-"+direction, "50px");
```

If you want to use object format then, you can use the bracket notation to assign dynamic properties

```
var css = {};
css["margin-"+direction] = "50px";
$('#elem').css(css);
```

Comment: Is there anyway to do it with the brackets { }  so I may use multiple properties in the css() ? because I need to do this: .css({opacity:0, display:"block", "margin-" + direction: "50px"}}).promise().done(function(){

Comment: @RON you can use this syntax:-   css({"propertyname":"value","propertyname":"value",...});

Comment: @RON2015 see the update... again the use of promise is of no use here as `css` does not do any async operation

Comment: @Arun P Johny how would you fire off a function after css() then?

Answer (score 0):

Remove Curlybraces({,}) and colon (:) in your jquery code, and try the below code

```
var direction = "left";
$('#elem').css("margin-"+direction, "50px");
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create JAVASCRIPT object and then you can apply that object in to CSS.

**Sample code:**

```
var style = {property1:"value1", property2:"value2", property3:"value3"};
```

Then you can use below syntax to apply above property.

```
$('#element').css(style);
```

By using above way you can add dynamic properties and that would be apply using jQuery.

Hope this helps.